# RPM: unit tests per subpackages in the %check section

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have this rpm that contains multiple subpackages and for each subpackage there should be a couple unit tests , according to docs, rpm support unit testing by using the **%check** directive.
But i want to make sure that each subpackage runs it's own tests.
What i want to know is there any other way to divide the tests per subpackage, sort of like the spec file below(this won't work because it says that each spec file should have one **%check**)

```
Name:                               Software
Version:                            1.0
Distribution:                       el7
Summary:                            Software divided to subpackages 
Group:                              Development

Source:                             Software1.0.tar.gz
Provides:                           software-package = %{sversion}
Requires:                           softlib = %{sversion}

%build

%package subpackage1
Requires:                           reqlib1 = 1.4
Provides:                           provlib1 = 1.5
Obsoletes:                          obslib1 = 1.0


%package subpackage2
Requires:                           reqlib2 = 1.4
Provides:                           provlib2 = 1.5
Obsoletes:                          obslib2 = 1.0

%install
#install script

%clean
#clean script

%check subpackage1
./test_subpackage1


%check subpackage2
./test_subpackage2


%files subpackage1
path-to-file-1

%files subpackage2
path-to-file-2
```

Comment: I've never tried to subpackage `check` so I'll leave this as a comment but not an answer. I would say you'll have to build in some smarts and look for certain files to know what subpackages are present and then have them run, *e.g.* `if test -e /path/test_subpackage1; then /path/test_subpackage1; fi` This assumes you've tried subpackages on the `%check` directive and they were rejected. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add comment so I am adding this as answer.

Currently more than one %check is not supported. I think you could raise a issue similar like this to have this functionality.
https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/311

Till then I think you can try the way Aaron suggested.